# EPPlus:Cannot access a closed Stream when copy existing excel worksheet

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, epplus, memorystream

I'm currently using EPPlus and right now I'm trying to copy existing worksheet from an excel file and add the copied worksheet to another excel file. But then, Ive encounter this error:

**Full Stack Trace**

```
System.ObjectDisposedException: Cannot access a closed Stream.
   at System.IO.MemoryStream.Seek(Int64 offset, SeekOrigin loc)
   at OfficeOpenXml.Packaging.ZipPackagePart.GetStream(FileMode fileMode, FileAccess fileAccess)
   at OfficeOpenXml.Packaging.ZipPackagePart.WriteZip(ZipOutputStream os)
   at OfficeOpenXml.Packaging.ZipPackage.Save(Stream stream)
   at OfficeOpenXml.ExcelPackage.Save()
   at OfficeOpenXml.ExcelPackage.SaveAs(Stream OutputStream)
```

**Excel Helper**

```
  public byte[] ExportStraightBoxClampPreview(PreviewInputDto input)
        {
            //the path of the file
            string filePath = @"C:\Preview\WeldedStraightBox.xlsx";
            string filePath1 = @"C:\Preview\Strongback.xlsx";



            //create a fileinfo object of an excel file on the disk
            FileInfo file = new FileInfo(filePath);
            FileInfo file1 = new FileInfo(filePath1);
            FileInfo file2 = new FileInfo(filePath2);
            //create a new Excel package from the file

                using (ExcelPackage strongBack = new ExcelPackage(file1))
                using (ExcelPackage excelPackage = new ExcelPackage(file))
                {
                    ExcelWorksheet wsSrc = strongBack.Workbook.Worksheets.First();
                    ExcelWorksheet wsDest = excelPackage.Workbook.Worksheets[wsSrc.Name] ?? excelPackage.Workbook.Worksheets.Add(wsSrc.Name, wsSrc);



                  ** error here **------> return excelPackage.GetAsByteArray();
                }
```

Is it because I do not use Memory Stream? But then If I manually copied using looping for each row and column, it is working:

**another method**

```
                    ExcelWorksheet wsSrc = strongBack.Workbook.Worksheets.First();
                    ExcelWorksheet wsDest = excelPackage.Workbook.Worksheets[wsSrc.Name] ?? excelPackage.Workbook.Worksheets.Add(wsSrc.Name);

                for (var r = 1; r <= wsSrc.Dimension.Rows; r++)
                {
                    for (var c = 1; c <= wsSrc.Dimension.Columns; c++)
                    {
                        var cellSrc = wsSrc.Cells[r, c];
                        var cellDest = wsDest.Cells[r, c];

                        // Copy value
                        cellDest.Value = cellSrc.Value;

                        // Copy cell properties
                        cellDest.Style.Numberformat = cellSrc.Style.Numberformat;
                        cellDest.Style.Font.Bold = cellSrc.Style.Font.Bold;
                        // TODO... Add any additional properties that you may want to copy over
                    }
                }
```

I'm really sorry for the lack of knowledge about this. I'm really appreciate any help.

Comment: The error seems somewhere else. There is no `SaveAs` or `Save` in your posted code. And `ExportStraightBoxClampPreview` works fine.

Comment: @VDWWD hello Sir, sorry for the late reply. I already try put Save or SaveAs but the same problem still occur.

Comment: did you manage to resolve this? I want to do the same thing, right now I'm copying cells ranges, but it does not copy over sizes.

Comment: Hi @KrzysztofSkowronek, Sorry for taking long time to reply this. But for my issue it is because I got image inside the other worksheet. It is unable to copy the image. So I had to remove it first and add the image back after copying. I'm not sure about copying cells range. Sorry once again.

Comment: no problem, I just used the ms office API to copy the sheets, then EPPlus to edit. Nasty workaround, but works